# How do I get my Bootstrap webpage to have a full width

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.2'` in my Rails application.

How do I get my navigation and boy content to stretch, so it is 100% of the width?

My `application.haml` looks like this:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico"
    %title= "My website"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    %header
      %nav
        .container
          .tabbable.tabs-below
            %ul.nav.nav-tabs
              = render 'layouts/navigation'
    #main{:role => "main"}
      .container
        .content
          .row
            .span12
              = render 'layouts/messages'
              = yield
          %footer
```

And then I have a css file with these settings:

```
$bodyBackground: #fff;
@import "bootstrap";

body { padding-top: 10px; }

@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of .container, .row and .span and replace with your own div with width 100%

Comment: But I am using many of the Bootstrap 2 features. Can't this be done using Bootstrap 2?

Comment: Adding `body { padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; }` does not help unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm it could be due to the column gutters' padding or margin. Ill take a look at the documentation

Comment: Maybe get rid of .container, .row and .span and replace with your own div with width 100%.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks. Could you put it into your answer, then I will close up the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.row-fluid` instead of `.row` and change `.container` width.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/julienvignolles/x7LkM/

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">aaa</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doc: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem